# Which gnome function is responsible for switching workspaces?

Tags: javascript, overriding, gnome, gjs

Gio open "http://..." from terminal switches from the current workspace to the workspace where the default browser is. And the same happens when the links are opened from other apps (email etc.).

I would like to write a extension and I have tried to override a lot of functions in js/ui. Some of them prevent workspace switching for example by keyboard, but nothing seems to prevent workspaces from changing with those links. I guess that d-bus activation has something to do with this, but as this is my first exploration of gnome I feel a little bit lost here.

So, I would like to override a gnome function which is responsible for workspace switching. Basically I would like to prevent all switching and then continue from there. It is said [in Mutter reference manual](https://developer.gnome.org/meta/stable/meta-MetaCompositor.html) that when the active workspace is changed, meta_compositor_switch_workspace() is called first. Javascript version of this is in js/ui/windowManager.js:_switchWorkspace(shellwm, from, to, direction).

If I override that function, nothing happens. No errors. Is this a wrong function? Am I doing something wrong? Should i override that meta_compositor_switch_workspace myself instead of _switchWorkSpace? And if I should do that, is there any help somewhere?

```
const Meta = imports.gi.Meta;
const Main = imports.ui.main;
const WindowManager = imports.ui.windowManager;


function mySwitchWorkspace(shellwm, from, to, direction) {
    log("in my switchWorkspace");
    //if ... {
    //        shellwm.completed_switch_workspace();
            return;
    //    }
    }

let old_sw = {};

function init() {
    old_sw = WindowManager.WindowManager.prototype._switchWorkspace;
    log(old_sw);
}

function enable() {
    WindowManager.WindowManager.prototype._switchWorkspace = mySwitchWorkspace;
    log(WindowManager.WindowManager.prototype._switchWorkspace);
}

function disable() {
    WindowManager.WindowManager.prototype._switchWorkspace = old_sw;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The architecture of GNOME Shell and how it relates to extensions is not immediately obvious, so while you're on the right track, you're missing a bit of perspective here.

Mutter is a library for window managers, while GNOME Shell is technically a Mutter plugin. The implementation of [`Meta.Plugin`](https://gjs-docs.gnome.org/meta6%7E6_api/meta.plugin) in GNOME Shell is [`Shell.WM`](https://gjs-docs.gnome.org/shell01%7E0.1_api-wm/). In the JavaScript code of [`windowManager.js`](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-shell/blob/gnome-3-36/js/ui/windowManager.js#L590) the variable pointing to the `Shell.WM` is `windowManager._shellwm`:

```js
// windowManager.js Line #590
this._shellwm.connect('switch-workspace', this._switchWorkspace.bind(this));

// windowManager.js Line #1799
_switchWorkspace(shellwm, from, to, direction) {
}
```

In the code above, you can see that `Shell.WM::switch-workspace` is [bound](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) to `this._switchWorkspace()`. Although you have overridden that function, `Function.prototype.bind()` creates a new function instance, so a copy of the original callback is being invoked instead of yours.

In this case, no handler ID was stored so you'll have to disconnect the signal using the new helpers in `gjs >= 1.64` (GNOME 3.36):

```js
let shellwm = global.window_manager
let handler = GObject.signal_handler_find(shellwm, {signalId: 'switch-workspace'});
shellwm.disconnect(handler);
```

Once done, you should be able to connect your override like a normal signal callback, then later replace the original handler.

```js
// Replacing the original handler when your extension is disabled
function disable() {
    shellwm = global.window_manager;
    wm = imports.ui.main.wm;
    shellwm.connect('switch-workspace', wm._switchWorkspace.bind(wm));
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and answer. However, I have a problem. When i try to disconnect the signal, function always returns zero hits. What should I use as a shellwm? Global.window_manager or the windowmanager._shellWM? And how can I get the windowManager._shellWM, if that is my problem?

Comment: You can use either `imports.ui.main.wm._shellwm` or `global.window_manager`, since both point to the object emitting the signal. Hmm...that function seems to have a bug, but you can still use `GObject.signal_handler_find()` with the same arguments and then call `global.window_manager.disconnect(result)`. I'm reporting the bug to the project :)

Comment: Thanks again. Just what I was looking for :)